# Server 2008R2 on my laptop will not connect to the internet

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I am running a dual boot system Server 2008R2 and window7, and have built a Hyperion Essbase Planning and HFM Sandbox on my Laptop.  MY laptop has the following specs an I7 – QM3610 Intel chip benchmark @ 8991. With 8 GB ram and a 750GB Hard Drive. The server has 200GB of Space on the windows side has the balance of the hard space
On the Server side I cannot connect to the internet

Answer (score 1):

Wifi or Ethernet

If you can't connect to wifi - you don't have the service installed, open add a role wizard, then skip role, go to services, add wifi and voila.

If you cannot connect over wired and you set static IPs on your router, make sure they're outside your DHCP addressing and reboot